# Using Jmeter, I need to add UUID extracted from JSON in CSV in same column (multiple values of UUID) So to pass in Delete Path

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

Using Jmeter, I need to add UUID extracted from JSON and add that in CSV in same column (multiple) to feed in Delete Request (REST). This is to test multiple delete calls which has unique UUID generated from POST call. Or is there any other way I can test multiple delete call after extracting from POST calls. Lets say 50 Post then 50 Delete calls.

Comment: can you show your test plan ? do you submit 50 users ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do anything as given threads reside in the same [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you should be able to use the same variable for the Delete request.

JMeter Variables are [local to a thread](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so different threads will have different variable values.

---

If you are still looking for a file-based solution be aware of fact that you can write an arbitrary JMeter Variable into a file using Groovy code like:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) after the JSON Extractor
2. Make sure you have `groovy` selected in the "Language" dropdown
3. Make sure you have `Cache compiled script if available` box ticked
4. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def csvFile = new File('test.csv')
   csvFile << vars.get('your_variable')
   csvFile << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   ```

This way you will get any extracted UUID written into `test.csv` file in JMeter's "bin" folder, you can use it in the CSV Data Set Config for your Delete request.

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Working with Files](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-files.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Actually in case of multiple UUID returned I need to save them under a column name "Path" in excel saved as extension csv. I am not getting the same.